# JBOSS Developer Studio - GIT Commit error - There are no staged files

Tags: git, jboss

I am using Jboss developer studio. I created a sample Java project and then trying to upload my project in GIT repository. First I created a local repository. Then i gave commit.

I am getting the below error message.

[image]

Can anyone advice to resolve this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to select all the files in the unstaged changes and then I have to drag it to the staged changes. After that I pressed commit. It was working fine.